# How does POST request work with relative path in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, post, postman

I am analyzing code from a HTML page, and saw that when the page is loaded, there will be a POST request as the following:

```
$.post('/video_info/html5',{v:video_id},function(data){
    //it does something here with data    
},'html');
```

The page URL is in format: `https://example.com/watch?v=123#video=456`.
So then, I was trying to use Postman to send a POST request to `https://example.com/video_info/html5` with parameter v = video_id (for example: `The_Lord_of_the_Rings_2002`), but it doesn't get any response while the code above can get it(I used firebug and could see the response).

Is there something wrong in the URL: `https://example.com/video_info/html5` ?

Comment: Nothing wrong with the URL itself, but you can't make AJAX requests to an  external domain using JavaScript. You can thank the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: The response is `succeed`?

Comment: @anmarti yes, the response is `succeed`

Comment: If you return a `Json` from the controller you should get the response using `data.YourField`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Sr, but Im not familiar with AJAX, what I saw here is just jQuery and HTML, JS. Can you tell me how you can know there is some AJAX stuff here?

Comment: `$.post` makes an AJAX request

Comment: Please, can you post the controller `html5` code to see how you return the response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there something wrong in the URL: https://example.com/video_info/html5 ?

No, that's the correct resolution of the URL in the `post` (ajax) call relative to the page URL you've described.

`ajax` requests carry headers and such which may make them look different from other requests. The site in question may also be looking at the `referer` (sic) and/or keeping server-side track of the fact that page X was just loaded from IP 1.2.3.4 and so it's okay to reply to the request for the video.

People sometimes go to great lengths to protect their content from being used except in the ways they want it used.

Comment: Is there any way to send such a POST request from outside domain to get the same result?

Comment: @MrCold: From a *server*, yes, *(almost)* anything can be spoofed. From a *browser*, probably not, you're likely to run into the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).